# How to use simplified boolean value t|f in CnosDB query?

Tags: cnosdb

I'm using CnosDB v2.4.0, followed [document](https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/v2.4/reference/sql.html#data-types), but there is sstill something that confuse me.

As the document says the syntax of BOOLEAN type is `{true | false | t | f}`, I can INSERT boolean value use simplified boolean value `'t'`, but it doesn't work in SELECT statements. Here are some statements I have tried.

The INSERT statements.

```
public ❯ CREATE TABLE table_a(is_conv boolean, tags(ta));
 
public ❯ INSERT INTO table_a(time, ta, is_conv) VALUES (now(), 'r1', true);
+------+
| rows |
+------+
| 1    |
+------+

public ❯ INSERT INTO table_a(time, ta, is_conv) VALUES (now(), 'r2', t);
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Schema error: No field named t."}

public ❯ INSERT INTO table_a(time, ta, is_conv) VALUES (now(), 'r2', 't');
+------+
| rows |
+------+
| 1    |
+------+

public ❯ SELECT * FROM table_a;
+-------------------------------+----+---------+
| time                          | ta | is_conv |
+-------------------------------+----+---------+
| 2024-01-06T19:02:46.880107100 | r1 | true    |
| 2024-01-06T19:02:56.199697400 | r2 | true    |
+-------------------------------+----+---------+
```

The SELECT statements.

```
# The normal boolean value
public ❯ SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE is_conv = true;
+-------------------------------+----+---------+
| time                          | ta | is_conv |
+-------------------------------+----+---------+
| 2024-01-06T19:02:46.880107100 | r1 | true    |
| 2024-01-06T19:02:56.199697400 | r2 | true    |
+-------------------------------+----+---------+

# The simplified boolean value
public ❯ SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE is_conv = 't';
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: type_coercion\ncaused by\nError during planning: Boolean = Utf8 can't be evaluated because there isn't a common type to coerce the types to"}

public ❯ SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE is_conv = t;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Schema error: No field named t. Valid fields are table_a.time, table_a.ta, table_a.is_conv."}

public ❯ SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE is_conv = "t";
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Schema error: No field named t. Valid fields are table_a.time, table_a.ta, table_a.is_conv."}
```